# Android Preferences activity change before function ends

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I want to change the visualization of preferences activity before the method ends to show a message or progressbar.

```
buttonSave.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {  
                buttonSave.setTitle(getString(R.string.loadingWait));//visualization to change before the next function ends
                back();//this function takes a long time      
             //   buttonSave.setTitle(getString(R.string.bSave));
                return true;
            }
    });
```

How Can I do that? Other possibility is shows a progressbar, but I can show it before the function back() ends.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should look at AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Anything in `doInBackground` will be executed on a separate thread, while all the other methods (like `onProgressUpdate` can manipulate the UI, because that's on the UI thread again.

So you could do something like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        buttonSave.setTitle(getString(R.string.loadingWait));
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        back();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        //Show any progress
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        //Anything necessary when the background task is done
    };
}.execute();
```